# How to change the order of packages updating with Chocolatey?

Tags: windows, sorting, software-update, chocolatey

When executing `cup all -y` it looks like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) updates all the packages *alphabetically*. Is there an option to change this behavior to sort the packages by size, and then install largest or smallest packages first?

I checked `cup all -h`, but I failed to discover an appropriate key for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known option currently. It would be best to file a request to have the functionality at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/new.

You can also see if an issue exists prior to filing at issue at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues (in this case I don't believe one exists, so go ahead on filing an issue).

Thanks!